# How spring recognises after reading xml that beans needs to be implemented as beanfactory style or applicationcontext style

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible for me to give a different name to ApplicationContext.xml?

As I have seen the answer here that we can change the applicationcontext file name, SO how spring recognises that its a applicationcontext or beanfactory?

Comment: Which "name" are you referring to?

Comment: @skaffman Actually I am confused how spring will come to know its beanfactory or applicationcontext. Previously I used to think that by the name only it signifies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! You just have to change in the web.xml (if you are using web application).

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/Spring/applicationContext-services.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 3):

yes you can:
you can find several examples on how to do it here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-introduction

theere are ways concerned with web containers as well as stand alone applicaitons.

Answer (score 0):

The filename doesn't matter.   You can call it foo.xml if you want.

The type of `ApplicationContext` that is created depends on how it is created.

For example, if you are using `ContextLoaderListener` in `web.xml` then it's going to create a `XmlWebApplicationContext` (unless you specify a different class to use).

If you are creating the context programmatically then you are specifying the type of context to create.

Under normal circumstances you will always be creating a `ApplicationContext`, not a `BeanFactory`.  `ApplicationContext` extends `BeanFactory` - implementations delegate their `BeanFactory` methods to a private `BeanFactory` that they contain.